# Slack command to Google Script returning Timeout Error

Tags: google-apps-script, slack

I setup a custom slash command to store data into a Google Spreadsheet. Everything works perfectly (the script gets triggered and does its magic) **except** the respond takes too long (more than the given max of 3000ms) and Slack throws me a `timeout` error.

**simplified google script:**

```
function doPost(request) {

   //// get data from slack payload
   var params = request.parameters;

   //// call a function with given parameters
   custom_function(params); 

   //// 
   var output = {"text":"SUCCESS"};

 //// respond to slacks POST request
 return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(output)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

}
```

**Result:** 
Due to the long execution time of `custom_function();` the end `return ContentService. ...` comes too late (past 3000ms timelimit) = `timeout` error in slack

**Additional Info:** I setup delayed responses with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);` with the code of `custom_function();` - I am receiving those responses in Slack together with the timeout error.

**Question:** Is there any way I DON'T have to wait until `custom_function();` is finished and send some `HTTP 200 OK` back immediately ? The `doPost();` in my case doesn't need anything from `custom_function` in return to finish so why wait ... ?

THANKS !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a time based trigger to run the code in the future. Specifically the `after` method of ClockTriggerBuilder can run the code x milliseconds in the future.

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)

```
function doPost(){

 //execute the the script function "myFunction" 100 ms in the future
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .timeBased()
    .after(100)
    .create();

 return ContentService.createTextOutput("OK");
}
```

Comment: So the post script sets up the trigger, finishes the code and after x milliseconds my custom_function gets triggered ? Didn't expect it to be so simple :D ... trying this right now ! Thanks !

Comment: So setting up the Trigger works like a charm, and it actually triggers the function. The only thing: how would i pass the given parameters that I received from Slack to that function ?  With `Class PropertiesService` ?

Comment: Thanks @Spencer Easton ! It now works like A+ ! I needed to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` when storing all the values to PropertyService but hey ... it works :)

Comment: Guys, it would be very useful to have the complete example with the PropertiesService. Thanks!